# How do I show this result?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This is regarding measure theory/probability. Basically my problem is this:

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots$ be independent events. Define

\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}_n &= \sigma\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\} \qquad \text{for $n \geq 1$} \\
\mathcal{A}_n' &= \sigma\{A_{n+1},A_{n+2},\dots\} \qquad \text{for $n \geq 0$}
\end{align}
and
$$
\mathcal{T} = \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathcal{A}_n'.
$$

Suppose $A \in \mathcal{T}$. Show that there exists a sequence $E_n \in \mathcal{A}_n$ such that
$$
P(E_n \triangle A) \to 0 \qquad \text{as $n \to \infty$}.
$$

I'm not sure how to show that. Apparently it uses another lemma, which says:

Suppose that $\mathcal{F}_0$ is an algebra that generates the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$, that is, $\mathcal{F} = \sigma\{\mathcal{F}_0\}$. For any set $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a set $A_{\epsilon} \in \mathcal{F}_0$ such that
$$
P(A \triangle A_{\epsilon}) < \epsilon.
$$

I can kind of see how it might work (loosely speaking, let $E_n = A_{1/n}$). The problem is that $\mathcal{T}$ isn't generated by $\mathcal{A}_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the lemma, for any given $A \in \mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{A}'_k$, there exists $E_k \in \alpha\{A_{k+1},A_{k+2},\ldots\}$ (the algebra generated by $A_{k+1},A_{k+2},\ldots$) such that $P(E_k \triangle A) < 1/k$. By the definition of an [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets), $E_k$ can be constructed using finitely many sets from $\{A_{k+1},A_{k+2},\ldots\}$, so it lies in $\mathcal{A}_{n_k}$ for some large enough $n_k$.

Since this holds for any $k$, and WLOG one can choose $(n_k)_{k \ge 1}$ to be an increasing sequence, we have a sequence $E_k \in \mathcal{A}_{n_k}$ such that $P(E_k \triangle A) \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.

To fill in the gaps so that you have a sequence of sets in all $\mathcal{A}_n$ and not just in $\mathcal{A}_{n_k}$, simply note $E_k \in \mathcal{A}_{n_k} \subset \mathcal{A}_{n_k+1} \subset \cdots \subset \mathcal{A}_{n_{k+1}-1}$, so you can "repeat" the set $E_k$ in the sequence.